# Exporting data from a gridview to different excel worksheets

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am binding data from a dataset to a grid and exporting data from the grid to an excel.if the the number of items in the grid is greater than 50000,an error message is displayed.

So i want to split the data and display it in different worksheets in excel.(Am working in a web application)

using this code for exporting to excel

```
gvExcel.DataSource = DTS;
gvExcel.DataBind();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= filename.xls");
         Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gvExcel.RenderControl(htw);
        // Style is added dynamically
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
```

Can anyone help me on this??

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need to actually use the Excel API and create the document, not just an HTML version of it. Using the HtmlTextWriter is a bit disastrous and I hate downloading documents that use it because it's always a mess. I have to re-save it as an xls (because its really just HTML) and go through the process of fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Following links will be useful to do so..

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/ExportDataSetToExcel.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/BlogDetail.aspx?BlogId=283

Hope this will help!